504 Timeouts after setting django CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS
I have a django 5.0 site deployed to elastic beanstalk with a domain and https through cloud front.
When i make POST requests without the CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS setting set, i get 403 errors.
When i set the CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS setting, i get 504 timeouts.
I have tried SSH'ing into the box and running the POST directly against the django site-- it does the timeout there too. So it's definitely not AWS. Something with django.
I've also tried downgrading to django 4-- didn't work either.
Everything works perfectly locally.
Any ideas?

turns out the timeout was the db timeout bubbling up. had nothing to do with csrf at all
